# Assign to array, adding multiple copies of index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

So I have this array, right?

```
a=np.zeros(5)
```

I want to add values to it at the given indices, where indices can be duplicates.

e.g.

```
a[[1, 2, 2]] += [1, 2, 3]
```

I want this to produce `array([ 0.,  1.,  5.,  0.,  0.])`, but the answer I get is `array([ 0.,  1.,  3.,  0.,  0.])`.

I'd like this to work with multidimensional arrays and broadcastable indices and all that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`np.add.at`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) to get around the buffering issue that you encounter with `+=` (values are not accumulated at repeated indices). Specify the array, the indices, and the values to add in place at those indices:

```
>>> a = np.zeros(5)
>>> np.add.at(a, [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3])
>>> a
array([ 0.,  1.,  5.,  0.,  0.])
```

`at` is part of other ufuncs too (multiply, divide, and so on). This method will also work for multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are performing can be looked at as binning, and to be technically more specific, you are doing *weighted bining* with those values being the weights and the indices being the bins. For such a binning operation, you can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html).

Here's the implementation -

```
import numpy as np

a=np.zeros(5)        # initialize output array

idx  = [1, 2, 2]     # indices
vals = [1, 2, 3]     # values

a[:max(idx)+1] = np.bincount(idx,vals) # finally store the bincounts
```

**Runtime tests**

Here are some runtime tests for two sets of input datasizes comparing the proposed `bincount` based approach and the `add.at` based approach listed in the [`other answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30236606/3293881):

Datasize #1 -

```
In [251]: a=np.zeros(1000)
     ...: idx = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,1000,(500))).tolist()
     ...: vals = np.random.rand(500).tolist()
     ...: 

In [252]: %timeit np.add.at(a, idx, vals)
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.4 µs per loop

In [253]: %timeit a[:max(idx)+1] = np.bincount(idx,vals)
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.4 µs per loop
```

Datasize #2 -

```
In [254]: a=np.zeros(10000)
     ...: idx = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,10000,(5000))).tolist()
     ...: vals = np.random.rand(5000).tolist()
     ...: 

In [255]: %timeit np.add.at(a, idx, vals)
1000 loops, best of 3: 597 µs per loop

In [256]: %timeit a[:max(idx)+1] = np.bincount(idx,vals)
1000 loops, best of 3: 404 µs per loop
```